# $cordovaOauth Error in Ionic Cordova mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, oauth

I am making Google login in my Ionic + Cordova mobile application.
my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','starter.services','ngSanitize',  'ngCordova', 'ngCordovaOauth', 'facebook'])
```

My Controller

```
.controller('login',['$scope','myService','$location','$state','$timeout',function($scope,myService,$location,$state,$timeout, $http, $cordovaOauth)
{

 $scope.googleLogin = function(){
  $cordovaOauth.google("640286280543-pgr2pqnk0clc7qmobsvgkuno2fin7opd.apps.googleusercontent.com", ["email","profile"]).then(function(result) {

  $scope.showProfile = false;
  $http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me", {params: {access_token: result.access_token }})
  .then(function(res) {
$scope.showProfile = true;
   $scope.details = res.data;
console.log(res.data)
}, function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error);
  });
  },function(error) {
    // error
    $scope.details = 'got error';
})
}
```

}])
[followed this Tutorial. Click me!](https://www.sitepoint.com/authenticating-users-via-oauth-with-cordova-and-ionic/)

My Error:

> Error: $cordovaOauth is undefined
>   $scope.googleLogin@http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:53:3

Comment: what is at 53:3 in your controller.js?

Comment: provide your whole controller. and also make sure that you have injected $cordovaOauth in your controller .Thanks